# How to write Scala Play framework custom class's multiple JSON serializer deserializer?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, deserialization

I have following class need to serializer deserializer

```
 case class User(userId: Int, userName: String, email: String,        
 password: String) {

 def this() = this(0, "", "", "")

def this(userId: Int){
this(userId, "", "", "" )
}

def this(userId: Int, userName: String){
  this(userId, userName, "", "" )
}

def this(userId: Int, userName: String, email: String){
  this(userId, userName,email, "" )
}

def this(password: String){
  this(0, "","", password )
 }
}
```

I have User case class with multiple constructor. So that User can be created as

1. var u = new User(mid, mname, memail, mpassword)
2. var u = new User(mid, mname)

I am expecting JSON request as

JSON request type 1:-

```
 "teamMembers" : [ {
    "userId" : 1,
    "userName" : "user name",
    "email" : "eamil",
    "password" : "password"
  }, {
    "userId" : 2,
    "userName" : "user name 2",
    "email" : "email2",
    "password" : "pssword"
  } ]
```

OR JSON request type 1:-

```
"teamMembers" : [ {
    "userId" : 1,
    "userName" : "user name"
  }, {
    "userId" : 2,
    "userName" : "user name 2"
  } ]
```

My implemented JSON serializer deserializer which is working fine as follows only for type one request

```
  trait UserJson extends Controller {
  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
      (__ \ "userId").write[Int] ~
      (__ \ "userName").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "email").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "password").write[String]
    )(unlift(User.unapply))

   implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
      (__ \ "userId").read[Int](min(0) keepAnd max(150)) ~
      (__ \ "userName").read[String](minLength[String](2)) ~
      (__ \ "email").read[String](minLength[String](2)) ~
      (__ \ "password").read[String](minLength[String](2))
    )(User.apply _)
}
```

But for type 2 JSON request is not working. Could you please let me know how to plement for for type 2 JSON request? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `email` and `password` are `Optional`. you can set `email` and `password` as `Option` and use `writeNullable` as shown below. is that what you are looking for?

on a side note: your `this` `def`s are looking odd, in Scala generally you use `apply` for achieving that.

```
case class User(userId: Int, userName: String, email: Option[String],  password: Option[String])

implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
  (__ \ "userId").write[Int] ~
  (__ \ "userName").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "email").writeNullable[String] ~
  (__ \ "password").writeNullable[String]
)(unlift(User.unapply))
```

Comment: I'm just learning scala. So don't know much. Could you please explain replace def this with apply. I need multiple constructor for User class. Could by all default value to null or 0 or only one of them provided. How to do it with apply? Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json Reads/Writes not as implicit value

For example:

```
Json.toJson(user)(userWrites1)
Json.toJson(user)(userWrites2)
```

Comment: what is userWrites1 and userWrites2? Is it something similar to my implemented userWrites or a new implementation or User class writter

Comment: userWrites1 is Writes for Json Request type 1